# Using CitusDB with SQL-alchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, citus

I am using [caravel](https://github.com/airbnb/caravel) with CitusDB and I am running into problems connecting to the database node. To be frank, I have no clue what to do.

I followed the official [installation instructions](https://www.citusdata.com/docs/citus/4.0/installation/single_node_deb.html#single-node-deb) to install and run.

I can log into the running master using the `psql` script in `/opt/citusdb/4.0/bin` but I can't connect to it from the application. Flask-SQLAlchemy supports the postgresql dialect and driver and the server running seems to be on the 5432 port. I am trying it with `psycopg2`.

I have turned off the `postgresql` service because that was interfering with the master node start-up.

This is the error:

```
2016-04-28 10:10:53,487:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:DB Creation and initialization failed: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `@Ahmet Eren Başak` I was able to look at problem from a new angle.

The key to this problem was the pid file of the running server. `psycopg2` and `postgresql` in general refer to the `/var/run/postgresql/` directory to see if the server is running. CitusDB apparently does not have permission to edit/create files in this directory. Hence, the pid file is created in `/tmp/`.

The solution was to link this file to `/var/run/postgresql/` and that solved it

```
ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a permissions problem so much as a problem with the Citus 4.0 build. It may use `/tmp` on all platforms, whereas a "regular" PostgreSQL install uses `/var/run/postgresql` on certain platforms. It's likely Citus 5.0 and higher no longer have this problem at all, but good job finding the workaround!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I strongly suggest using Citus 5.0. The document you have followed is about CitusDB 4.0 version, which was a fork of PostgreSQL. Currently, Citus can be installed as an extension to PostgreSQL 9.5 and has lots of new features and bugfixes. You can take a look at [Citus installation instructions](https://www.citusdata.com/docs/citus/5.0/index.html#installation) for 5.0.

If it is not possible to switch to Citus 5.0, then the problem may be related to socket file paths. Could you try issuing the command [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161371)?